# Querying table data?

Tags: php, search, dynamic, html-table, dropdown

I am quite new to PHP and was wondering the best way of querying my table using both a drop-down and search feature? Have looked at various guides etc but can't get the jist yet. I am using the following code to list said table:

```
$sqlQ = 'SELECT w_Continent.ID, w_Continent.NAME, w_Country.Name, w_Country.Continent
    FROM w_Continent JOIN w_Country  
    ON w_Continent.ID = w_Country.Continent
    ;';
$stmtRow = $db->query($sqlQ); //execute sql query
            while ($rowOne = $stmtRow->fetchObject()) {
<td><?php echo $sqlQ->Name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sqlQ->Name;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php>
```

Comment: Kind of a broad topic. I guess the answer would be `prepared statements` though.

Comment: Sorry...I'm currently intending on listing said table using the code above, and allow people to search for countries using a country name, and filter the countries using a continent which is listed in a dropdown, both of which are listed in the table above...if that clarifies.

Comment: Okay, so instead of an HTML table use a `form` and use `select` with `option`... or use JS and submit checked values. There really are a lot of ways to do this. It is more a UI/UX question it sounds like.

Comment: Edit, it worked but it has put all rows of data, and there is multiple rows with the same continent, meaning it is listing as such: Africa, Africa, Africa, Africa

Comment: Would need to see the new code and sample records.